# Does anyone succeeded with Open Stack Single Installer?

Tags: juju, openstack

Tried steps as mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/single-install.html) on Ubuntu14.04 LTS. But I'm Hitting keystone: hook failed: "config-changed" error.  Can someone help me how to proceed further ??

Answer (score 0):

Single install method is deprecated in favor of http://conjure-up.io. You'll need to upgrade to Xenial and run `conjure-up openstack` in order to do a single installation. This utilizes the new Juju 2.0, and LXD bits to accomplish a private cloud on your laptop/desktop.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will upgrade to Xenial and post the results..

Comment: upgraded to Xenial  and i'm hitting below errors with  "conjure-up openstack" command  
when I chose OpenStack Base for MAAS.

"Unable to list controllers: {}".format(sh.stderr.decode('utf8')))
LookupError: Unable to list controllers: /bin/sh: 1: juju: not found

Comment: Looks like you dont have juju installed?

Comment: able to deploy to open-stack after juju installation.  But now facing  same problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/829027/conjure-up-openstack-lxd-console-not-working