# conjure-up openstack LXD console not working

Tags: juju, openstack, conjure-up

I was able to install LXD base openstack with conjure-up.  Dash-board and Juju GUI is accessible. And I am also able to create instance without any errors. However Console is not accessible.  Can someone help in isolating the issue?

Below are the screenshots attached:

[image: running instance]

[image: console error]

Comment: Just want to mention that noticed  ¨ vnc_enabled = False¨ in  /etc/nova/nova.conf  .  I don't think can  change this considering juju would  override this

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to make sure that **console-access-protocol** is defined:

```
juju config nova-cloud-controller console-access-protocol=novnc
```

Here is the yaml option describing this:

```
  console-access-protocol:
    description: |
      Protocol to use when accessing virtual machine console. Supported types
      are None, spice, xvpvnc, novnc and vnc (for both xvpvnc and novnc)
    type: string
    value: novnc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also directly attach to the lxc on the hypervisor.

```
lxc exec lxc-name -- /bin/bash
```